# HomeController" not found. You need to call "Get.put(HomeController())" or "Get.lazyPut(()=>HomeController())"

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am using getX. I just need once the application opened, the data from database shown. I created a future function inside the repository and need to auto-display it. if it call this function inside **onInit** inside the controller the lat variable will not be initialized yet. i need to call this function inside the binding but this error occurs.

```
HomeController" not found. You need to call "Get.put(HomeController())" or "Get.lazyPut(()=>HomeController())"
```

**The Code Inside Binding Is:**

```
   Get.lazyPut<IHomeRepository>(
      () => HomeRepoFirebaseImplimentation(),
    );
    // Get.lazyPut<HomeController>(
      Get.putAsync(
      () async=>await HomeController(homeRepository: Get.find()).fetchProductsFromDB(),
    );
```

Comment: did you bind the binding on the getpage?

Comment: yeah, i did @ArbiterChil

Comment: did you manage to solve it? I'm going through the same problem. :(

Answer (score 2):

*I was experiencing the same problem, and nothing worked.*

But studying my structure further and in more detail, I had the following **tree**:

```
BasePage
 | -> HomePage
 | -> CartPage
 | -> OrdersPage
```

And what happened was that I was trying to put the binding on my `HomePage` directly, but as my base that would do the navigation through the `PageView`, **I needed to create a `Binding` in the `Base` that stores the `Controller`s of each view**.

**This made it work perfectly.**

---

- More practically, I did this:

  ```
  class BaseBindings implements Bindings {
    @override
    void dependencies() {
      Get.put(HomeController());
      Get.put(CartController());
      Get.put(OrdersController());
    }
  }
  ```
- And in getPages I did the following:

  ```
  GetPage(
    name: '/base',
    page: () => const BasePage(),
    binding: BaseBindings(),
  ),
  ```

---

This made the application work normally and I had more peace of mind in the development; **that's what worked**.